# calculate the percentage change of every nth row in the dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the percent change in the values of the dataframe. Now the rows for which the percent change has to be calculated is entered by the user. If the user enters 2 then for every 2nd row the percentage change will be calculated. I have the following function:

```
change <- function(DF, change) {
   numCols <- ncol(DF)
    for (i in 1: numCols) {
      pctChange <-rep(NA,nrow(DF))
        x<-DF[,i]
        y<-c(DF[(change+1):nrow(DF),i], rep(NA,change))
        pctChange <-round((y-x)*100/x,2)
        DF$pct<-pctChange
        colnames(DF)[ncol(DF)]<-paste(colnames(DF[i]),"pctChangeby",
                                                    change,sep = "")
      }
      return (DF)
    }
```

When i tested this function:

```
change(mtcars[1:5], 1)
```

I got the following output:
(just showing output for first row:

```
                   mpg       mpgpctChangeby1
Mazda RX4           22.8            7.02
Mazda RX4 Wag       24.4            -6.56
Datsun 710          22.8           42.11
Hornet 4 Drive      32.4            -6.17
```

Expected Output:

```
                 mpg       mpgpctChangeby1
Mazda RX4           22.8            NA
Mazda RX4 Wag       24.4           7.02
Datsun 710          22.8           -6.56
Hornet 4 Drive      32.4            42.11
```

For change = 2,

Expected Output:

```
                    mpg       mpgpctChangeby2
Mazda RX4           21.0            NA
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0            NA
Datsun 710          22.8            8.57
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4            1.90
Hornet Sportabout   18.7          -17.98
```

Comment: check the length of x and y. it should be different. Use `print(x); print(y)`. After I commented (`#`) some lines of code, change(mtcars[1:5],1)
[1] 32
[1] 33
[1] 32
[1] 33
[1] 32
[1] 33
[1] 32
[1] 33
[1] 32
[1] 33

Comment: The other way i was trying to solve this problem was by: Creating a new data.frame of numbers of rows = nrow(DF) and number of columns as the number of columns of the results. `df[,i] <- c(NA,diff(DF[,i]) / head(DF[,i],n-1))` But this can only be used it we enter 'change' as 1 in the function.

Comment: I just deleted my solution after I noticed your comment.  It would be better if you post the output you wanted for the first column of mtcars for change=2.

Comment: @akrun, I have edited the post. I fixed earlier issue. Can you please take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running your function `change`, I am getting a different output than the one you showed.

```
  change(mtcars[1],1)[1:4,]
 #               mpg mpgpctChangeby1
 #Mazda RX4      21.0            0.00
 #Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0            8.57
 #Datsun 710     22.8           -6.14
 #Hornet 4 Drive 21.4          -12.62
```

I guess this would help in getting your expected output:

#### For change=2

```
  mtcars1 <- mtcars[,1] #1 column
  x <- c(rep(NA,2), mtcars1[-((length(mtcars1)-1):length(mtcars1))])
  y <- c(rep(NA,2), mtcars1[-(1:2)])
    round(100*(y-x)/x,2)
  # [1]     NA     NA   8.57   1.90 -17.98 -15.42 -23.53  34.81  59.44 -21.31
 #[11] -21.93 -14.58  -2.81  -7.32 -39.88 -31.58  41.35 211.54 106.80   4.63
 #[21] -29.28 -54.28 -29.30 -14.19  26.32 105.26  35.42  11.36 -39.23 -35.20
 #[31]  -5.06   8.63
```

#### For change=3

```
 x <- c(rep(NA,3), mtcars1[-((length(mtcars1)-2):length(mtcars1))])
 y <- c(rep(NA,3), mtcars1[-(1:3)])
 round(100*(y-x)/x,2)
 # [1]     NA     NA     NA   1.90 -10.95 -20.61 -33.18  30.48  25.97  34.27
 #[11] -27.05 -28.07  -9.90 -14.61 -36.59 -39.88  -3.29 211.54 192.31 130.61
 #[21] -33.64 -49.01 -55.16 -38.14  23.87  79.61  95.49  58.33 -42.12 -24.23
 #[31] -50.66  35.44
```

Regarding the change=1, the values you showed for `mpg` are not matching with the rownames.  By changing your function:

```
 change <- function(DF, change) {
 numCols <- ncol(DF)
 for (i in 1: numCols) {
  pctChange <-rep(NA,nrow(DF))
    x<- c(rep(NA, change), DF[-((nrow(DF)-(change-1)):nrow(DF)),i])
    y<-c(rep(NA, change), DF[-(seq_len(change)),i])
    pctChange <-round((y-x)*100/x,2)
    DF$pct<-pctChange
    colnames(DF)[ncol(DF)]<-paste(colnames(DF[i]),"pctChangeby",
                                                change,sep = "")
  }
  return (DF)
}

 change(mtcars[1],2)[1:6,]
#                   mpg mpgpctChangeby2
#Mazda RX4         21.0              NA
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0              NA
#Datsun 710        22.8            8.57
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4            1.90
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7          -17.98
#Valiant           18.1          -15.42

change(mtcars[1],3)[1:6,]
change(mtcars[1],1)[1:6,]
```